# showing promises' loading state

Tags: javascript, ember.js

ok, this might be a complicated one:
I have a controller that loads additional data depending on several options.
In the corresponding template a component is called that shall display that data.
What I want to achieve is to display a `loading` state while loading that data.
I finally managed to do that with that (here very reduced) code:
*(basicly I set a parameter on the promise-callbacks an pass that into the component)*

```
// controller
fetchedEvents: Ember.computed('filterEventsSwitchFuturePast', function() {
    let _this = this;
    this.set('loadingEvents', true);
    if(this.get('filterEventsSwitchFuturePast')) {
        let promise = this.store.query('event', {..some filters here...} });
        promise.then(function() { //promise resolved
                _this.set('loadingEvents', false);
            });
        return promise;
    } else {
        let promise = this.store.query('event', {..other filters here...});
        promise.then(function() { //promise resolved
                _this.set('loadingEvents', false);
            });
        return promise;
    }
}),
```

..

```
// template calling the component
    {{event/event-list
            events=fetchedEvents
            isLoading=loadingEvents
    }}
```

which gives me a loading State in that component which resolves once all the data is loaded. All fine til here.

Now **here comes my problem**:

I need to have the `fetchedEvents` computed property depetend on the model's related `events` - so that, when I add a new event, the list get's updated.
So I added `model.events` to the observed properties:

```
// controller
fetchedEvents: Ember.computed('filterEventsSwitchFuturePast', 'model.events', function() {
     //....the rest is the same as before!
}),
```

Now the list get's updated, **but** my beutiful property `loadingEvents` seems bouncing between it's states. It starts not loading, then loads for a second, goes back to not loading - *but with zero results!* - and finally hits it's correct final state.
The result is a UI that keeps saying *- no results - loading - no results - here's the results*.
Not a realy lovely UI, I'd say.

The route's/component's/template's model is loaded and shown far before that happening, so I don't think hooking in there might be a solution.

Do you guys have any suggestions how I could solve/improve that?
Any other hooks I can get into?

I'm on *Ember 2.0*

Comment: How are you trying to use the `fetchedEvents` property/promise in your component (where it is apparently called `events`)? Please show us the JS or HBS or both. With promises, having flags such as `loading` is often an anti-pattern, and there's usually a better way. Off the top of my head, it seems better to make `fetchedEvents` an observer which refetches when `filterEventsSwitchFuturePast` changes, and updates the relevant data directly after the `query` finishes, but it's hard to say without looking at a little bit more of your code.

Comment: thanks, I refactored my code to an observer that sets the refetched data to another property and also updates the 'loading' flag. This is now working as expected!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's caller's obligation to resolve the promises before they get passed to component (event-list)

```
fetchedEvents: [],

somethingChanged: function() {
   if(Ember.isNone(x) && Ember.isNone(y)) return;

   this.set('isLoading', true);
   var promise;

   if(this.get('x')) {
      promise = "firstFilter"
   } else {
      promise = "secondFilter"
   }

   promise.then(resolved => {
      this.set('isLoading', false);
      this.get('fetchedEvents').pushObject(resolved); 
   }, reportErrors); 

}.observes('model.events.[]', 'longNamedThingy')
```

Comment: yes, refactoring my code to an observer that updates the data and the loading state did the job! Thank you!